# header navigation line breaks

Tags: html, css

I have a site header created with floating divs using this structure:

```css
nav {
    height:inherit;
    width:100%;
    margin:0 auto;
    position:relative;
    z-index:10;
    text-align: center;
}
#nav-wrap {
    min-width: 100%;
    width: auto !important;
    width:100%;
    white-space:nowrap;
}
nav ul#nav-left, #nav-right {
    list-style-type:none;
    display:inline-block;
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    width:auto;
    height:100%;
}
nav img {
    display:inline-block;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
    max-height:225px;
    vertical-align:top;
}
nav ul li {
    display:inline-block;
    text-align:center;
    font-family: 'Oswald',helvetica,arial,sans-serif;
    font-size:1.8rem;
    font-weight:400;
    padding:0 30px;
    margin-top:30px;
}
```

```html
<nav>
  <div id="nav-wrap">
    <ul id="nav-left">
      <li>Option1</li>
      <li>Option2</li>
      <li>Option3</li>
    </ul>
    <img src="assets/img/img.png" />
    <ul id="nav-right">
      <li>Option4</li>
      <li>Option5</li>
      <li><a href="#contact">Option6</a>
      </li>
    </ul>
</nav>
```

## Updated

I've been playing with layout and the floats were making things tough. So, it's all displayed as `inline-block` without floats, but the center logo still isn't resizing and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Take a look at the staged site linked below to see what I'm going for. The logo overlap is intentional.

## [Staged site](http://dev.ohheybrian.com/parkerhouse)

I appreciate any help or suggestions. I'd like to avoid using `display:table` if possible.

Comment: Well it is pushing your right nav down because you have no float on your `a img` and it is inside your nav.  Also you will need to reduce the size.  Try using `@media` queries.

Comment: Ok, didn't think about the image float. I do have `@media` queries that kick in at 760px, I'm just trying to avoid writing half a dozen cases.

Comment: Ok.  Well floating currently will reduce the image size to fit your nav, but that is a start and will fix the content from pushing down on the right.

Comment: I added a float to the center image and it isn't sizing. I think it's because the image flows beyond the navbar, which is intentional. I'll switch it to a table layout and see if that helps.

Answer (score 0):

`@media` queries is the thing you needed.

```
@media (max-width: 700px) {
    nav ul li {
        font-size:1.3rem;
        padding:0 10px;
    }
}
@media (max-width: 1200px) {
    nav ul li {
        font-size:1.5rem;
        padding:0 20px;
    }
}
@media (min-width: 1201px) {
    nav ul li {
        font-size:1.8rem;
        padding:0 30px;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 400px) {
    nav ul li {
     /*For this you need to use mobile friendly menu        **/
    }
}
```

Comment: Yeah, I know I can use media queries, but I wanted to avoid having to guess at which five or six I needed to write. I'd rather have a fluid menu using relative sizes because it's cleaner markup, too.